# Who can override an approval for a Release Stage in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I just  created my first CI-CD pipeline with approvers for a release stage. I noticed that I can override the approvers and I was trying to figure out who else can override. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find much information about this.
So I guess my questions are:

1. Was I able to override because I am the owner of the release pipeline?
2. Was I able to override because I am the owner of the release?
3. Can a Release Admin override the approver?
4. Can a Project Admin override the approver?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on my test, the users who have the `Administer release permissions` can override the approver.

1. Select the specific Release Pipeline => `Security`
2. Select the specific User/Group then set the `Administer release permissions` to `Allow`.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add this to the documentation? These permissions not being listed with the other user/group permissions assignments is very confusing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#release-permissions

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Andy-Li-MSFT's answer above, the settings can be set per-pipeline (as shown in his answer) or for the project as a whole (using the same three-dot menu button) on the Release pipelines main page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#build-object-level

The settings are not in the Permissions page under Settings like many of the other items.

There also doesn't appear to be an organization-wide setting, so make sure to set it for each new project.